# objective c delay in open page after scanning QR code

Tags: ios, qr-code

I'm quite new with ios developing (even though I have a lot of experience with other platforms) and I am facing an issue while I'm try to implement a QR code reader.
This is the piece of code I wrote:

```
- (BOOL)startReading {  
        NSError *error;  
        AVCaptureDevice *captureDevice = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];  
        AVCaptureDeviceInput *input = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:captureDevice error:&error];  
            if (!input) {  
                NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);  
                return NO;  
            }  
            _qrLB.text=@"Loading....";  
            _captureSession = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];  
            [_captureSession addInput:input];  
            AVCaptureMetadataOutput *captureMetadataOutput = [[AVCaptureMetadataOutput alloc] init];  
            [_captureSession addOutput:captureMetadataOutput];  
            dispatch_queue_t dispatchQueue;  
            dispatchQueue = dispatch_queue_create("myQueue", NULL);  
            [captureMetadataOutput setMetadataObjectsDelegate:self queue:dispatchQueue];  
            [captureMetadataOutput setMetadataObjectTypes:[NSArray arrayWithObject:AVMetadataObjectTypeQRCode]];  
            _videoPreviewLayer = [[AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer alloc] initWithSession:_captureSession];  
            [_videoPreviewLayer setVideoGravity:AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill];  
            [_videoPreviewLayer setFrame:_viewPreview.layer.bounds];  
            [_viewPreview.layer addSublayer:_videoPreviewLayer];  
            [_captureSession startRunning];  
        return YES;  
    }  
    #pragma mark  
    #pragma mark Stop reading QR Code  
    -(void)stopReading{  
        [_captureSession stopRunning];  
        _captureSession = nil;  
        [_videoPreviewLayer removeFromSuperlayer];  
    }  
    #pragma mark  
    #pragma mark Capture QR Code  
    -(void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput didOutputMetadataObjects:(NSArray *)metadataObjects fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection{  
        NSLog(@"qrcode1");  
        if (metadataObjects != nil && [metadataObjects count] > 0) {  
            AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject *metadataObj = [metadataObjects objectAtIndex:0];  
            if ([[metadataObj type] isEqualToString:AVMetadataObjectTypeQRCode]) {  
                [_lblStatus performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(setText:) withObject:[metadataObj stringValue] waitUntilDone:NO];  
                [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(stopReading) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];  
                _isReading = NO;  
            }  
        }  
        NSLog(@"Value of qrcodetext = %@", _lblStatus.text);  
        ReceiveVC *view = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ReceiveVC"];  
        view.imageURL=_lblStatus.text;  
        view.title = @"";  
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:view animated:YES];  
        NSLog(@"qrcode2");  
    }
```

When I launch the app on the device (iphone 5s) and I scan a QR code this is the output I got:

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4103n.png)

It works fine! it reads the value and it redirects the user to the page "ReceiveVC" ("ReceiveVC1" is a debug I print when the page at loading)
The problem is: it's taking like 20 seconds (sometime even more!!) from the moment in which the value is correctly read, to the moment in which the page is opened (check time of lines 2 and 3). Seems taht the navigationController is waiting for some thread to finish but I cannot figure out which one, since all the values I need are already there!
Can you help me?
Thank you

Comment: try the creating and opening the navigation controller with the following code dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        ReceiveVC *view = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ReceiveVC"];  
        view.imageURL=_lblStatus.text;  
        view.title = @"";  
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:view animated:YES];  
    });

Comment: Thank you very mucha Sateesh it worked! One question: the thread the app was waiting for.. do you think with this procedure it would be automatically killed?

Comment: In the above method the thread might be deallocated. I am not sure. why because its coming from OS.